# How to debug inside Rust macros

Tags: debugging, rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to debug an issue in Serde, and I can step through my code fine, but unfortunately Serde is like 90% macros, so it seems like the entire call to `deserialize()` gets mapped to the line containing `#[derive(Deserialize)]` and I can't set through it.

Is there any way around this? If it were code I have written I suppose I could use `cargo expand`, but it's in another crate so I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: What debugger are you using? What makes you think stepping into Serde's code is a good idea? Why can't you just set a breaking point into one of Serde's function?

Comment: Did you try `cargo expand`? It doesn't matter where the macros come from, it works for any, including built-in ones like `println`.

Comment: @mcarton: I'm using `lldb`, and why wouldn't it be a good idea to step into Serde's code?  @Peter Hall: Yes I did. The issue is that it only expands macros in *my* code. It doesn't help if I step into macro in Serde's code. (I did actually manage to solve my original issue using `cargo expand`, but the question still stands - how would I debug an issue in another crate's code that uses macros?)

Comment: It doesn't seems like a good idea to step into Serde's code because it's a well tested library with a lot a generated code. If you do think there is a bug in serde, then I'd place breakpoints (or a regular expression BP) to some interesting Serde methods.

Comment: That's silly. All software [has bugs](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1748).